# The fastest way to populate std::vector of unknown size

Tags: c++, memory-management, stdvector

I have a long array of data (*n* entities). Every object in this array has some values (let's say, *m* values for an object). And I have a cycle like:

```
myType* A; 

// reading the array of objects   
std::vector<anotherType> targetArray;
int i, j, k = 0;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
     for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
     { 
         if (check((A[i].fields[j]))
         {
             // creating and adding the object to targetArray
             targetArray[k] = someGenerator(A[i].fields[j]);
             k++;
         }
     }
```

In some cases I have *n* * *m* valid objects, in some (*n* * *m*) /10 or less.
The question is how do I allocate a memory for `targetArray`?

1. > `targetArray.reserve(n*m);
   >
   >   // Do work
   >
   >   targetArray.shrink_to_fit();`
2. Count the elements without generating objects, and then allocate as much memory as I need and go with cycle one more time.
3. Resize the array on every iteration where new objects are being created.

I see a huge tactical mistake in each of my methods. Is another way to do it?

Comment: Did you consider using some other container, e.g. `std::dequeue` instead of `std::vector`  ??

Comment: Will it be adding memory on every creation?

Comment: Have you considered `vector::reserve()`?

Comment: @jroc Yes, `vector::reserve()`.

Comment: I don't see it in your question. `resize()` and `reserve()` do different things.

Comment: Edited, made it right. Yes, resize will be not enough to alloc memory.

Comment: `sizeof(myType)` in the call to `reserve` is wrong. `n*m` will reserve enough space for `n*m` objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are doing here is called premature optimization. By default, `std::vector` will exponentially increase its memory footprint as it runs out of memory to store new objects. For example, a first `push_back` will allocate 2 elements. The third `push_back` will double the size etc. Just stick with `push_back` and get your code working.

You should start thinking about memory allocation optimization only when the above approach proves itself as a bottleneck in your design. If that ever happens, I think the best bet would be to come up with a good approximation for a number of valid objects and just call `reserve()` on a vector. Something like your first approach. Just make sure your shrink to fit implementation is correct because vectors don't like to shrink. You have to use `swap`.

Resizing array on every step is no good and `std::vector` won't really do it unless you try hard.

Doing an extra cycle through the list of objects can help, but it may also hurt as you could easily waste CPU cycles, bloat CPU cache etc. If in doubt - profile it.

Comment: So, if it is 129 objects to store, output vector will have size of 256 objects in the end? Will `shrink_to_fit()` after working  fix it? And it's not my implementation of shrinking used here, it's just standart `std::vector`s method.

Comment: If you continuously push_back, then yes - 256 is what you get unless you reserve it to 129 manually before pushing. If you are using C++11's `shrink_to_fit`, then it should do the job.

Answer (score 4):

The typical way would be to use targetArray.push_back().  This reallocates the memory when needed and avoids two passes through your data.  It has a system for reallocating the memory that makes it pretty efficient, doing fewer reallocations as the vector gets larger.

However, if your check() function is very fast, you might get better performance by going through the data twice, determining how much memory you need and making your vector the right size to begin with.  I would only do this if profiling has determined it is really necessary though.